# my phone won't reboot from fastboot mode it keeps coming back to fastboot mode

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, fastboot, usb-debugging, flashtool

I wanted to flash recovery.img in my phone but I accidentally flashed boot.img and now my phone is stuck in fastboot mode.

Comment: Can you not just flash `recovery.img` from fastboot (`fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`)? What command did you use to flash `boot.img`?

Comment: I used " fastboot flash boot boot.img " command I don't even know if it was right but the command was executed

Answer (score -1):

Download stock boot.img for your phone and flash it using same command

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. It would help, if you answer with code snippets rather than simply stating ambiguous answers